# Lenovo IdeaPad 700 bios password

Tags: bios, laptop

I've had a Lenovo IdeaPad 700 for several years now. After about a year of ownership, it malfunctioned, and I had to send it to warranty technical support. They repaired it (reportedly replacing the HDD) and it worked smoothly for a while. However, when I tried to install Linux, it unexpectedly prompted for a BIOS password that I didn't set.

I went back to the store where I purchased it to seek a solution. They assured me they hadn't set a password and contacted warranty technical support as well, who confirmed they hadn't set one either. The only solution they offered was to send it back for repairs again.

As I needed the laptop for my studies and couldn't wait for weeks without it, I requested a temporary replacement while mine was repaired. They agreed, but all their loaner laptops were unavailable at the time. They promised to call me when one became available.

I waited for some time (my warranty was nearing expiration) and returned a month later for an update. Unfortunately, they informed me the warranty had expired, so they couldn't assist further.

I eventually discovered a reset-like button on the side of the laptop, which allowed me to install an OS.

Now, I'm facing another hurdle: I need to install a virtual machine (VM) on my laptop, but I'm unable to activate the hypervisor. This option isn't accessible through the menu unlocked by the reset button.

I've already attempted resetting the password by removing the motherboard battery, but the prompt persists.  Additional password attempts like "bios," "password," "12345678," "0000000," and combinations of the serial number (limited to 8 characters) also proved unsuccessful.

Any idea of how can I reset that damn password?

Comment: Lenovo has a strict policy about removing a bios protection password. You may  reset your device by opening it up and taking out the battery and bios battery. But don't wait for minutes, it's better to wait for hours. Also, it's a good idea to keep pressing the power button during this process.

Comment: I've tried by removing the battery for serveral minutes. Today I'll take out the battery for the whole night just in case it needs more time. Thanks for the advice

Comment: i addition you can look into bios-pw.org which has somekind of information about a general workaround for older devices

Answer (score 0):

You state, "Now, I'm facing another hurdle: I need to install a virtual machine (VM) on my laptop, but I'm unable to activate the hypervisor."

Though using the board-level hypervisor and Windows hypervisor services might make a virtual machine more efficient, they are *not* required for all VM's. For example, Oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) runs nicely on a PC with hypervisor *disabled*, as shown below (It allowed me to run a 32-bit Windows 8 application and write 32-bit rescue media to USB, while operating on a 64-bit Window 10 OS).

[image: Disabled Hypervisor Services]